TensorFlow Estimator Prediction Error: Tensor Must Be From the Same Graph Issue
I have a TensorFlow code that involves using TFTransformOutput to transform raw features read from an existing recordIO of Tf.Examples and then feeding those transformed features into a warm started TensorFlow estimator.EstimatorV2 for predictions.
The entire process is managed within a single TensorFlow graph and session context to avoid graph mismatch errors potentially due to using both tf_v1 and tf_v2 in the code.
However, I keep encountering an error related to tensors being from different graphs. Below is the code and the error message I'm facing. I would really appreciate your help.
Trimmed code:
def main(argv: Sequence[str]) -> None:
...
  tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()

  def transform_features_fn(
      tf_transform_output,
      hparams,
      examples,
      used_features,
  ):
    """Creates an input function for serving based on ExampleMetadata."""
    feature_spec = tf_transform_output.raw_feature_spec()

    parsed_features = tf.io.parse_example(examples, feature_spec)
    transformed_features = tf_transform_output.transform_raw_features(
        parsed_features, drop_unused_features=True
    )
    return transformed_features

  # Define paths and parameters
  tf_transform_output_path = "/some/path"
  checkpoint_path = "some/path/2"
  testdata_filepattern = "some/path/3"

  # Load the transform output
  tf_transform_output = trainer_util.TFTransformOutput(tf_transform_output_path)

  # Define hyperparameters
  hparams = model_hparams.create_hparams()
  # Function to get records
  def get_records(records_list):
    for f in gfile.Glob(testdata_filepattern):
      with recordio.RecordReader(f) as rr:
        for record in rr:
          ex = example_pb2.Example()
          ex.ParseFromString(record)
          records_list.append(ex)
          return  # Return after one example for simplicity

  # Get records
  records_list = []
  get_records(records_list=records_list)

  # Define the graph context
  graph = tf.Graph()
  with graph.as_default():
    with tf.compat.v1.Session(graph=graph) as sess:
      # Serialize the example
      serialized_examples_tensor = tf.constant(
          [records_list[0].SerializeToString()]
      )  # Changed to batch of one serialized example
      # Transform features within the same graph
      transformed_features = transform_features_fn(
          tf_transform_output,
          hparams,
          serialized_examples_tensor,
          used_features,
      )

      # Define input function
      def input_fn():
        dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(transformed_features)
        dataset = dataset.batch(1)
        return dataset

      # Create the estimator within the same graph
      my_model = model.create_estimator(
          tf_transform_output,
          hparams,
          warm_start_from=checkpoint_path,
          model_dir=checkpoint_path,
      )
      predictions = my_model.predict(input_fn=input_fn)
      for prediction in predictions:
        print(prediction["predictions"])

Error Message:

E0603 04:04:15.467269 3556985 app.py:668] Top-level exception: Tensor("batch_size:0", shape=(), dtype=int64, device=/device:CPU:0) must be from the same graph as Tensor("TensorSliceDataset:0", shape=(), dtype=variant) (graphs are <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x51cc1ab7b9c0> and <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x51cc24427bc0>).
.......
raise ValueError(
ValueError: Tensor("batch_size:0", shape=(), dtype=int64, device=/device:CPU:0) must be from the same graph as Tensor("TensorSliceDataset:0", shape=(), dtype=variant) (graphs are <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x51cc1ab7b9c0> and <tensorflow.python.framework.ops.Graph object at 0x51cc24427bc0>).

I tried to put all the operations in a single TensorFlow graph and session context to avoid graph mismatch errors potentially but it didn't work.

Hi@AiWannabe,It looks like you're encountering an issue with TensorFlow's graph and session management, particularly when dealing with different graphs and sessions in TensorFlow 1.x and 2.x compatibility modes.The error message indicates that tensors from different graphs are being used together, which TensorFlow does not allow. This typically happens when operations or tensors are created in different graph contexts.You need to ensure that all TensorFlow operations and tensors are created within the same graph context.

Make sure that all TensorFlow operations are defined within the same tf.Graph and tf.compat.v1.Session. You should also make sure that the tf.TransformOutput and the estimator are created and used within this same context.
